# Only show Splash screen

Tags: java, android

My android code doesn't show main activity, it only shows splash screen and than close. It is unable to show the main Screen. I am going to share my all files except MainActicity. Kindly tell  me what m doing wrong

Here is splash.java:

```
    //splash.java
    package com.example.myapplication;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class splash extends AppCompatActivity {

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            Thread td=new Thread(){
               public void run()
               {
                   try
                   {
                        sleep(3000);
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex)
                   {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   finally
                   {
                            Intent it=new Intent(splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(it);

                   }
               }
            };td.start();
        }        
    }
```

Here is activity_splash.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:paddingLeft="16dp"
      android:paddingRight="16dp" >

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/age"
          android:layout_marginLeft="70sp"
          android:layout_marginTop="200sp"

         />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/splashText"
          android:layout_marginTop="450sp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
          android:textSize="18sp"
          android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

here is AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.birthdaycountdown">

      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
          android:supportsRtl="true"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
          <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

          </activity>

          <activity android:name=".splash">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>


      </application>

  </manifest>
```

Kindly ans this question am just a beginner in android.

Comment: Check the [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) for errors

Answer (score -2):

First check logcat what kind of issue you are facing.
share logcae issue also.

Comment: Use comments to get the clarifications or to give suggestions